# Call a class' function in the constructor. C++

Tags: c++

I was curious since I thought of the idea as a solution to improve the readability of my code for my assignment. When I create an object of a class, is there a way to call one of the object/class' functions inside the constructor? If I'm not explaining myself clearly enough just ask and I'll try to expound on it.

Comment: @Benjamin:  Just because it works when you try it does not mean it is correct C++.  This is a perfectly valid question and the answer is useful.

Comment: @Nemo: You're right of course.  It just seemed strange the way he phrased it "is there a way to".  As if he couldn't figure out how to do it.  If he had phrased it something like "is it safe to", that would be a different story.

Comment: True, I should have worded it better. Even saying "can I" may have been a bit better.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Of course you can...

### ... But beware of virtual methods

There is only one catch, though: Avoid calling virtual methods as you won't call the most derived method, only the most derived for that class. For example:

```
class A
{
   public:
      A() { std::cout << "A::A()" << std::endl ; }
      virtual void foo() { std::cout << "A::foo()" << std::endl ; }
} ;

class B : public A
{
   public:
      B() { std::cout << "B::B()" << std::endl ; this->foo() ; }
      virtual void foo() { std::cout << "B::foo()" << std::endl ; }
} ;

class C : public B
{
   public:
      C() { std::cout << "C::C()" << std::endl ; }
      virtual void foo() { std::cout << "C::foo()" << std::endl ; }
} ;

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
   C c ;
   return 0 ;
}
```

The output will be:

```
A::A()
B::B()
B::foo()
C::C()
```

When you create a `C` object, the constructors will be chained: First `A()`, then `B()`, then `C()`. And as we know by reading the code, the `B()` constructor calls `foo()`, which is a virtual method.

In C++, the method called by `B()` will be the `foo()` method which is:

- the most derived possible
- and still defined in B or one of B's base classes

And for the current code, the right method is `B::foo()`.

### But why?

When  you are executing the B constructor of the C object, only the A and B parts of C have been constructed. The C part isn't constructed yet, so trying to access C's data from B's constructor would probably crash your code, and is a semantic error anyway.

So we must avoid that. The only normal way to access C's data from one of the B's methods is using virtual methods which are overridden by C.

So, to avoid that, virtual methods are not "fully resolved" in constructors and destructors (which suffer from the same problem, for the same underlying reasons).

Note that this C++ behavior is different from Java and C#'s.

Comment: I'm glad you put in the part about `B::foo` vs. `C::foo`, I wasn't sure if the standard made that defined behavior or not.

Comment: @Mark Ransom : I've first heard about that in B. Stroustrup's "C++ Programming Language", p414 : *[In a hierarchy of "base -> derived" Storable -> Component -> Receiver [...] -> Radio] "if the constructor of Component calls a virtual function, it will invoke a version defined for Storable or Component, not not one from Receiver [...], or Radio. At that point of construction, the object isn't a Radio; it is merely a partially constructed object. It is best to avoid calling virtual functions during construction or destruction".* I'll try to find the quote in the standard for completeness' sake.

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can, as long as it is not a virtual function. Calling a virtual function from the constructor will often not do what you expect and possibly invoke undefined behaviour as the object (especially derived classes) may not be fully initialized.

Comment: No, calling virtual functions from the constructor does not invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: The behaviour is only undefined if the function is pure virtual in the class under construction. Otherwise, it's dispatched as if the dynamic type were the class under construction (which may be surprising if you override the function in a more derived class).

Comment: @MikeSeymour: that a good addition. Thanks. I amended my text

Answer (score 2):

Calling functions in a constructor is no problem. Calling virtual functions in a constructor which are overriden in a derived class can be a problem in C++, but that is perhaps not what you want to.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with calling another member function from within the constructor, just make sure that the object is properly initialized first so that the function doesn't fail.

This can be quite handy to break out initialization into a common function that can be called from outside the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You can call any non-virtual member function from the class ctor with no problem. Avoid virtual calls, as they are likely to fail to do what you expect them to do.

```
struct foo {
    foo() {
        call_me();
    }
    void call_me() {
        std::cout << "something" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is totally fine. Just call the function as you would anywhere else.

Comment: NO! Make sure the function is not virtual, as that's undefined behavior.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore - No, calling virtual functions from the constructor does not invoke undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

No issues here, this is perfectly fine.  This is of course assuming a few things:

The function is defined.
 The variables, objects etc that the function is using are initialized.
 The function is not virtual.

Of course, with the exception (haaahhhh) of the last one, you should be checking for these when calling functions regardless of where you're calling them from.